# Remove custom menu pages for admin users

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, admin-menu

I've added some custom menù pages to my WordPress dashboard using the `add_menu_page()` function. I need to remove these pages for super admin roles, but the `remove_menu_page()` seems not working. This is the code I have in my plugin

```php
    function remove_default_menu_pages()
    {
        if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){
            remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
            remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'profile.php' );
            //remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=authorizer' );
        } 
        //TOFIX
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=dashboard' );
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=messages' );
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=contacts' );
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=calendar' );
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=filemanager' );
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=learning-center' );
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=polls' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_default_menu_pages' );
```

Is there something wrong into the code or I need a separate function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the slug of the pages as parameter, e.g. `remove_menu_page( 'dashboard' );` instead of `remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=dashboard' );`.

Comment: Already tried but not works, I suspect there is more to investigate or a different hook to use